# On wsl1, getting clipboard contents using powerhshell changes terminal appearance…?

Tags: terminal, powershell, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clipboard

I posted this on stack (now deleted), but was told that this might be a more appropriate forum.

I'm on windows-subsystem-linux 1 with Ubuntu with the <s>Windows</s> Ubuntu terminal.

Using advice from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17819814/how-can-you-get-the-clipboard-contents-with-a-windows-command

I'm calling powershell to output the contents of the clipboard to a file, as in:

`powershell.exe -command "Get-Clipboard" > myFile.txt`

This completely changes the appearance of my terminal and I think I might be running powershell, or something. See "before" and "after redirecting to a file", below. It also truncates my terminal after about ~3/4 of the screen.

You'll note that the window description now says "powershell.exe". But I can still run linux commands, and I have access to functions and aliases defined in my bashrc, so it's not like I'm suddenly in a powershell environment.

What's odd is that if I run, `powershell.exe -command "Get-Clipboard"` (ie without redirecting) it outputs the clipboard contents to the terminal without affecting my terminal appearance.

Typing `ctrl-c` does nothing. `ctrl-d` or typing `exit` just kills the terminal.

Any ideas about what's going on?

Before:

[image]

After redirecting to the terminal:

[image]

After redirecting to a file:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for reposting over here.  I did try this out when I saw the other question, and I wasn't able to reproduce it.  It's entirely *too* coincidental that both you and @jeff-tang came across this today (within hours of each other).  Did you install or update anything recently (Windows Terminal, Windows, etc.)?  I'm thinking (based on the fact that I can't reproduce it yet, and the fact that at least two people came across it today), that it's probably a bug introduced in a new release of something.  But just not sure yet.

Comment: I'm on Windows Terminal 1.4.3243.0, which is the latest that I see in the store.  I tested under both WSL1 and WSL2, both with bash (and also sh, and fish shell) on Ubuntu 20.04 with all packages up to date as of a couple of days ago.  I've tried `powershell.exe -command get-clipboard | cat` and `powershell.exe -command get-clipboard > /dev/null`.  Everything is still intact on my terminal after this.

Comment: Odd though it may be, I think it actually is a coincidence. I've only been using wsl for a few weeks, and this was just the first time I've needed to do this. I had actually wondered if this was a wsl1 v wsl2 thing, but @jeff-tang's question said he was using wsl2. Also, someone I know tried this using the hyper terminal (https://hyper.is/) and apparently this doesn't happen.

Comment: Agreed, it could be just coincidence.  Since it's working for me, I think our best bet is to find the difference between my config and yours.  I'm about to back out some of my customizations from my Windows Terminal profile (fonts, etc.) to see if I can reproduce with something more "default".

Comment: Whoops. I'm not using the Windows terminal. I'm using the Ubuntu terminal. I did not realize those were different. That may explain the discrepancy.

Comment: Okay - so that does not happen when I actually use Windows Terminal. It's something specific to the Ubuntu terminal.

Comment: There we go.  I can reproduce it if I launch WSL through the Start menu with "Ubuntu".  Note that the terminal that launches with the "bash" command under the Start menu also is fine (I think this is the Windows "conEmu" terminal, but not 100% sure).  But I'd recommend upgrading to the new Windows Terminal anyway.  It's much more capable.  I'm guessing there's not much priority on fixing issues in the terminal that comes from the Canonical Ubuntu install, but I could be wrong.

Comment: I posted this same problem on stack overflow.   I've never used this command before today, so I don't know if this is a change of behavior.  I saw this command on reddit yesterday and thought it would be useful.

I've also redirected stderr so I don't think it's some weird console control codes.   And I'm not even sure if that's a windows thing or just an xterm/vt100 thing

Comment: @Jeff-Tang Do you start WSL through the "Ubuntu" command on the Start menu, or some other means?  We seem to have isolated it to a problem with that terminal.  The new Windows Terminal (from Microsoft, available in the Store) works correctly for both cmuyehara and myself.  You can also try launching with the "bash" command, which seems to work as well under that terminal.

Comment: This is under whatever terminal that runs when I run "Ubuntu".

I get the same behavior when I run under "bash" from the Start menu.

Comment: @Jeff-Tang Can you try it with [Windows Terminal](https://aka.ms/terminal)?

Comment: I can confirm that this behavior is specific to the Ubuntu terminal and does not happen under Windows Terminal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the comments and our testing, this seems to be a problem with the "Ubuntu terminal" (the terminal launched with the Ubuntu WSL distribution from the Windows Start menu).  Other terminals such as hyper.js, Windows Terminal (from Microsoft, in the Store), and the default Windows terminal (launched when you use the "bash" command from the Start menu) all seem to work correctly.

Recommendation - Install an alternate terminal.  My personal preference is Windows Terminal.

Comment: That's sufficient for me. I was a little concerned that it was causing multiple powershell processes to run, but I checked and that does not seem to be the case. Thanks for the help!

Comment: I stand corrected (not the first time).. I will delete my post. :P

Comment: Well, at least you caveated it with "As far as I'm aware ..." ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem with [older versions](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/280#issuecomment-517870239) of Windows PowerShell:

> There is a check in Windows PowerShell to see if the code page is supported by the Consolas font. The list is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/typography/font-list/consolas). UTF-8 65001 isn't in that list, so whenever Windows PowerShell identifies a code page that isn't supported by Consolas, it will change the font to Terminal. PowerShell Core 6.x doesn't have this code anymore so you don't see this behavior.

You need to [download and install a newer version of PowerShell Core (6 or later)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell) and rewrite your command to use `pwsh.exe` (which points to the newer PowerShell Core 6-or-later) instead of `powershell.exe` (which points to the older Windows PowerShell 5.1) like so:

```
pwsh.exe -command "Get-Clipboard" > myFile.txt
```