# Use clipboard through WSL?

Tags: windows, windows-subsystem-for-linux, clipboard, ioctl

I'm trying to get WSL to utilize my clipboard so I can update files from the output via `xsel -b > my-umatrix-rules.txt`. However, I'm getting the following error:

`xsel: Can't open display: (null) : Inappropriate ioctl for device`

I assume this has something to due with it being separately contained from Windows and therefore the clipboard itself. Is there a way I can get WSL to be able to look at the clipboard?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

###### From Windows clipboard to WSL

To get information *from* the Windows clipboard into WSL, use PowerShell and the Get-Clipboard cmdlet, like so:

```
powershell.exe -c Get-Clipboard > my-umatrix-rules.txt
```

###### From WSL to Windows clipboard

To send data *to* the Windows clipboard from WSL, the easiest way I know is to use `clip.exe`, like so:

```
cat my-umatrix-rules.txt | clip.exe
```

Note, while not applicable to this particular use-case, if you need to capture both output *and* error of an application in WSL to the Windows clipboard (a common scenario), just use normal Linux redirection, such as:

```
# <command> 2>&1 | clip.exe
ls kdkdkdkd * 2>&1 | clip.exe
```

Comment: This is perfect, thanks.

Comment: Most certainly.  By the way, if you happen to be using Ubuntu and use the terminal that comes with that distro, you could run into [this issue](https://superuser.com/questions/1617959/on-wsl1-getting-clipboard-contents-using-powerhshell-changes-terminal-appearanc/1617985#1617985).  Just so that you are aware of it and know that you can get around it by switching terminals.

Comment: I use windows terminal already, but thank you.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds I discovered that running powershell.exe within a WSL2 window changed the font.  Very annoying.  Your link is helpful.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds calling `Get-Clipboard` from WSL takes 700ms on average with my setup. If getting Windows clipboard data is something that only has to happen "every now and again" then that _might_ be acceptable; otherwise a faster solution is needed IMO.

Comment: Do you know of any way to make `clip.exe` accept non-ASCII characters?

Comment: @lindhe Let me know if [this](https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/10095#issuecomment-1602833117) helps?  It requires a bit of a hack since WSL 1.1.2 and later.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion! It says "command not found: pwsh.exe" when I run that in my WSL2 terminal, do I have to install something for it to be available? I do have other Windows programs in my path, like `clip.exe` and `notepad.exe`, so it's not disabled in WSL2.

Comment: @lindhe `pwsh.exe` is simply the latest version of PowerShell.  You can probably replace `pwsh.exe` with the older-version `powershell.exe` that will certainly be on your system (I can't recall for sure if it works the same here, but it probably does), but I do recommend upgrading to [the latest PowerShell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-on-windows?view=powershell-7.4).

Comment: Thanks! Yes, `powershell.exe` was on my system! And indeed, now the example you linked works. Very neat.