# Copy data from Linux console to Windowshost clipboard using Windows Terminal

Tags: windows-terminal

I'm using Windows Terminal to access my Linux boxes and I have a need for copying data from the Linux console to the Windows host clipboard, it that possible?

More specific I run a .Net core application on Linux which need to copy a string to the clipboard.

Comment: Have you try the following: Select the text you want to copy, press right-click. The text should be copied to the host clipboard.

Comment: Yes, I'm aware - it has to be done by code, (you don't even have to right-click, you can setup WT to copy selection right away)

Comment: I believe this is what you are looking for -- [Use clipboard through WSL?](https://superuser.com/questions/1618537/use-clipboard-through-wsl).  If not, let me know.

Comment: What if I'm on a "real" Linux terminal, e.g. Debian then I don't have clip.exe (or can I?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Linux shell:

```
printf $'\e]52;c;%s\a' "$(base64 <<<'hello world')"
```

Comment: Brilliant, thanks this is a great time saver

Answer (score 1):

I created this little script based on @MrCalvin brilliant answer:

```
# clipfile
#  - Sends a file into the windows terminal clipboard
printf $'\e]52;c;%s\a' "$(base64 ${1:?})"
```

Saves me loads of time copying files into clipboard for pasting into Windows apps.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).